# Get max(timestamp) for each group with repetition (IBM DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

**ANSWER**: Need to use LEAD and PARTITION BY functions. Please refer to Gordon's answer.

I have the following dataset :
[image]

I want to get rows 1,3,5,7 in the result set.

RESULT SET SHOULD LOOK LIKE :

```
11/10/2020 19:36:11.548955  IN_REVIEW
11/8/2020 19:36:11.548955   EXPIRED
11/6/2020 19:36:11.548955   IN_REVIEW
11/4/2020 19:36:11.548955   ACTIVE
```

Comment: Which db,ms are you using?

Comment: IBM DB2 is being used

Comment: what is the result that you get? I don't think that answer should be the correct one, IN_REVIEW is duplicated

Comment: With group by I do not get the desired result. i have posed my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions.  `LEAD()` gets the value from the "next" row, so filter only when the value changes:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LEAD(interac_Reg_stat) OVER (PARTITION BY Acct_No ORDER BY xcn_tmstmp) as next_interac_Reg_stat
      FROM TABLE
     ) t
WHERE interac_Reg_stat <> next_interac_Reg_stat OR
      next_interac_Reg_stat IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, since you are grouping by interac_Reg_stat, you will never get 2 separate rows for the IN_REVIEW status.  To get the result you want, you will need to add a sub-query to find all items with a certain interac_Reg_stat that are before another specific interac_Reg_stat.